# emacs verilog moide:full command that include verilog-library-directories

Tags: emacs, verilog

I use the Verilog mode from emacs.
My question is:
What is full syntax of command that includes verilog-library-directories ?

```
emacs --batch f.sv -q --eval='(setq-default verilog-typedef-regexp
".*_t$")' -f verilog-batch-auto
```

Answer (score 0):

For including verilog libraries I use the following comment at the end of the file:

```
// verilog-library-flags:("-y ../rtl")
```

I think then you can reuse this syntax for command line.

Comment: What can I do if I don't use this comment at the file ? @Viktorinox

Comment: I tried like that and it worked for me : emacs -q
  --eval='(setq-default verilog-library-flags "-y RTL_DIr")'